# Mechanism of thyroid hormone synthesis: iodation and free radical formation

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, biochemistry, kinetics

[image: Full synthesis of thyroid hormone from thyroglobulin in thyroid follicular cells]

In the synthesis of thyroid hormone, what part of the thyroid peroxidase hormone is specifically responsible for abstracting the free radicals from the aromatic side chains in the iodated tyrosine residues on thyroglobulin?

Also, why are some of the tyrosines converted to monoiodotyrosine, and others diiodotyrosine? Does this have to do with steric hindrance, or the ring de/activating properties of the thyroglobulin backbone, or something else?